# Why are my trick shot infinity pistols not working?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am level 8 o.p and I got Fire Trick Shot and Corossive Infinity Pistols. They don't work, the recoil is all over the place and they hardly do any damage. Does anyone know why this
is happenig?

Also I had 67 million dollars. I died one time and lost 25 million. I've heard of gear box taking stuff but I don't know, why they would take my money that I earned through selling many weapons at the venders?

Comment: What did you hear about "gear box taking stuff"? Where do they take the stuff to?

Comment: I just heard that rumor. That they had

Comment: There all kind of rumors. Money in Borderlands 2 is not "stuff", in the sense that it can not be taken or moved. It is just a number on your character that limits your game somehow. Why would a game studio "take" someone's imaginary money? Can't they just assign any number to any variable they wish? Answer is - game decreases your "money" for deaths, so you would think twice and die less. As for 25 million penalty for a character with 67 million - I don't believe you, sorry. Death penalty is 7%, screenshot or didn't happen :-)

Answer (score 5):

The recoil for the infinity pistol is not actually recoil. Aim the gun at the ground or a wall a decent distance from you and you will see that "recoil" is actually an infinity sign. They aren't called that just because of infinite ammo, borderlands fun fact. They are also not meant to do a lot of damage since they can fire forever, they are like a last resort if you are out of ammo. Like stated before you also lose money when you die, its a set percentage, this happened in the first one too if you played it.

Comment: Thanks for that. Umm actually i knew that, about the infinity i have about 20 of them but the 2 i recently got are bad my friend said i need to add more skill points to my recoil witch is wierd but it must be that because i got no other weapons that shake like that

Comment: I ment the trick shot infinitys

Answer (score 0):

Because of your problem with the infinity pistol I can't help you but the money you lose for dying is a percentage of your total money.
The percentage seem to be 14.29%.

Maybe [this](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:What_percent_of_your_money_do_you_lose_when_you_die?) post in another forum can help you.

Comment: It definitely seemed to be 7% since Bordelands 1 up to last year's fall when I stopped playing Borderlands 2.